# Сохранения классов в файл

Tags: c#, xml, файлы, сериализация

Есть класс

```
public class Element
{
    public int x;        
    public int y;        
    public Element Next;
    public Element() { }
    public Element(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

и есть **Лист** экземпляров этого класса.
Можно ли сохранить как-то сохранить этот лист, чтобы потом открыть его?
Пытался сделать через `xml` но все попытки приводили к `System.InvalidOperationException` в `System.Xml.dll`

Comment: У Вас каждый объект `Element` содержит в свойстве `Next` другой объект? Очень странная структура получается

Comment: @Sv__t что странного то? классический однонаправленный список. Одна из самых первых и самых простых изучаемых структур данных

Comment: Автор, приведите пример кода, который у вас отвечает за сериализацию. Тут имхо нужен механизм разворота списка в массив при сериализации, и обратно. Иначе получится вложенность, которая ни к чему тут.

Comment: @teran , уже все потер, сейчас как раз в массив переделываю

Comment: @teran 
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ElementCollection));
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, elements);//Здесь выдаёт ошибку
                string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
                File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, xml, Encoding.Default);

Comment: @teran, что такое однонаправленный список я знаю. Имел ввиду структуру xml. Есть ли смысл в этих "километровых" уровнях вложенности?

Comment: @Sv__t а кто говорил. что сериализовать надо в аналогичную структуру?

Comment: @DontSeeSharp, а `List<Element>`пробовали сериализовать?

Answer (score 0):

В таком виде все работает:

```
List<Element> list = new List<Element>; // заполненный список
try
{
    Serialize(list, dialog.FileName);
    var newlist = Deserialize(dialog.FileName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // обрабатываем исключение
}

public static void Serialize(List<Element> list, string file)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Element>));
    string xml;
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, list);
        xml = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
    File.WriteAllText(file, xml, Encoding.Default);
}

public static List<Element> Deserialize(string file)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Element>));
    List<Element> list;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        list = (List<Element>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня все получилось. Код писался на коленке и побыстрому, так что простите за отсутствие красоты и не соблюдение принципа dry.

```
public class Element
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Element Next;
    public Element() { }
    public Element(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var s = $"x = {x} y = {y} ";
        return Next == null ? s : s + $"{Next.ToString()}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var x = new Element(10, 20);
        var y = new Element(30, 40);
        var z = new Element(100, 300);

        x.Next = y;

        var list = new List<Element>();
        list.Add(x);
        list.Add(y);
        list.Add(z);

        using (var fs = new FileStream("1.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Element>));
            formatter.Serialize(fs, list);
        }

        using (var fs = new FileStream("1.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Element>));
            var result = (List<Element>) formatter.Deserialize(fs);

            foreach (var itemElement in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(itemElement.ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Результат вывода:

> Hello World!
>
> x = 10 y = 20 x = 30 y = 40
>
> x = 30 y = 40
>
> x = 100 y = 300

Результат XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ArrayOfElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Element>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <Next>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>40</y>
    </Next>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <x>30</x>
    <y>40</y>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <x>100</x>
    <y>300</y>
  </Element>
</ArrayOfElement>
```

Comment: Кстати вы можете просто сериализовать один объект элемент, оно подхватит ссылки и сериализует. На msdn есть хорошая информация кстати по сериализации вложенных объектов, советую погуглить, я думаю вам в скором времени пригодиться)

Всего доброго!

Comment: `XmlSerializer` никак не использует атрибут `Serializable`.